# Erase object in both base class vector and derived class vector

Tags: c++, vector, delete-operator

In the game I am designing, I have a derived class `Bullet` that inherits from the class `Model`. I have two vectors of `shared_pointer` for both of those classes. Every bullet is in the model's vector. Whenever a bullet reaches the end of its lifetime, it is then erased from the bullet's vector. Since that same object is in the model's vector, is there a quick way of erasing it as well? I can't use the index from the bullets vector because that index does not match its index in the model class. I tried creating a function that included `delete this` in the bullet class but that crashed the program and isn't recommended after some research. I thought about assigning each model an ID, getting the ID from the bullet before erasing it, and then erasing it in the model's vector based upon that ID. That to me doesn't sound like the best way of doing it. What are some alternate solutions?

Note: The vectors are defined as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Model>> models`. same goes for bullets

Edit: I first loop through the vector of bullets. If it is found that a bullet at the index is at the end of its lifespan, then the object at that index is erased (`bullets.erase(index)`). This can not be done in the models class, because the index is most likely different. I need the objects in both vectors to be erased for the actual object to go out of scope, and be destroyed, right?  The reason there is a bullets vector and a models vector is that some operations should only be done on the bullets check lifespan for instance. Some operations should be done on all models including bullets, for instance, calculate velocity. I tried separating bullets from models, but that lead to redundant code that could have been achieved if all models were in one vector.

Comment: *That to me doesn't sound like the best way of doing it.* -- If you had a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` based on the ID as being the key in the map, then that would be a superior way of doing things.  Also, if you decide to stay with vector, how many items are expected in the vectors?  If it's like 100 or so, then doing a linear search given the ID will incur very little overhead due to cache-locality of the vector's elements.

Comment: How are you deleting the bullet from its derived-class vector? Why can you not do the same thing in the base class?

Comment: I'm stuck on trying to figure out why you store `*this` in an object's vectors, and why seemingly redundant vectors are useful. Do you mean that you have two **`static`** vectors for the classes? (Not one vector per object, but one vector per class.) If so, mentioning `static` somewhere in the question might give readers a better picture of your situation.

Comment: @JaMiT I am using bullets.erase(index) to remove it from the bullets  vector. The reason for the two vectors rather than one is because some operations should only be performed on just the bullets, while other operations should be performed on all models (player, planets, NPC, etc.)  I thought about removing all bullets from the models vector, but then I ran into having to manually perform operations on the bullets that would automatically be done with all models. An yes, one vector per class, not object.

Comment: @AubreyChampagne The information from your latest comment should probably be in the question, as I find it to be useful background information (to the extent that I would tell you that your use of `shared_ptr` is questionable; `weak_ptr` is probably a better fit). However, one other detail: how do you get `index` when you remove a bullet from the bullets vector? Why not do the same thing in the base class?

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this would be to use some form of weak ownership. This is how entity component system usually work: You have a reference, call it a model or an entity doesn't matter. Make them all non-owner. If you insist on using `std::shared_ptr`, then you will have to use `std::weak_ptr` everywhere. Then, simply have one and only one place where you have all the `std::shared_ptr`. If you remove one of them, all the weak reference to it becomes invalid.

System that implements that won't usually use shared and weak pointer, but instead a pointer to the lifetime manager object (usually called entity manager or entity system) and also an identifier that is used to fetch the strong reference. That way, you keep having easy to use objects, and you get the benefit of having a single place to safely manage the lifetime of any game objects.

Comment: So, for instance, my models vector could be the the one place where everything is stored, then use ```weak_ptr``` for the bullets vector?

Comment: This is an option yes. I think there is a significant advantage to have a centralized place to manage the lifetimes of your object if you need to have control over it. The one place place where everything is stored contains shared pointers, and all the others weak ones.